# Independence of a family with random measures having independent increments.

Tags: probability-theory

First of all, sry for my stupid editing. I have restored my first question and also kept my second version at the bottom, so future readers won't be too confused.

Let $\mathcal{N}$ be a family of random measures on a measurable space $(E,\mathcal{E})$, where all of its members have independent increments, i.e. for all $N\in\mathcal{N}$ the r.v. $N(\omega,A_1),\dots,N(\omega,A_n)$ are independent for all $A_1,\dots,A_n\in\mathcal{E}$ disjoint.

Then I want to show that it suffices to show independence of $N^{1}(\omega,A),\dots,N^{n}(\omega,A)$  for any finite choice $N^1,\dots,N^n\in\mathcal{N}$ and $A\in\mathcal{E}$ to get independence of $\mathcal{N}$.

I have already shown that the independence of $\mathcal{N}$ is equivalent to the independence of the familiy of random variables $\mathcal{M}:=\{N^i_{A_j}:=N^i(\omega,A_j),1\leq i,j\leq n\}$. But now i fail to proof their independence using that all $N^{1}_A,\dots,N^{n}_A$ are independent.

I even fail trying to proof the independence of two elements of $\mathcal{M}$ The main problem is to show the independence of two elements $N^i_{A_j}$ and $N^{k}_{A_l}$ for $i\neq j$ and $k\neq l$.

All help/tips/tricks are very much welcome!

Second version: I reconsidered the problem in my first (now deleted) post and I guess it all breaks down to the following question: Are $X_1$ and $X_3$ independent if $X_1$ and $X_2$, $X_2$ and $X_3$, $X_3$ and $X_4$, $X_4$ and $X_1$ are independent?

Comment: The modified (current) version is not equivalent to the former question: one should add some condition similar to the independence of $X_1+X_2$ and $X_3+X_4$.

Comment: no, put $X_1 = X_3$ and $X_2 = X_4$ and $X_1, X_2$ independent

Comment: OP: You seem to use "transient" for "transitive" (but both are improper in this context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $E=\{1,2\}$, $\mathcal E=2^E$, and $\mathcal N=\{N,M\}$, and use the notation $N_i=N(i)$ for $i$ in $E$. The hypothesis is that each of the couples $(N_1,M_1)$, $(N_2,M_2)$, $(N_1,N_2)$, $(M_1,M_2)$ and $(N_1+N_2,M_1+M_2)$, is independent. On the other hand, $\mathcal N$ is independent if the quadruple $(N_1,N_2,M_1,M_2)$ is independent.

Assume furthermore that every $N_i$ and $M_j$ is Bernoulli. Then the set of distributions on $E^4$ has dimension $2^4-1=15$. Two Bernoulli random variables are independent if their joint distribution satisfies $1$ relation. Since $N_1+N_2$ and $M_1+M_2$ have values in $\{0,1,2\}$ of size $3$, their joint distribution is described by $3^2-1=8$ parameters in general and by $2\cdot(3-1)=4$ parameters if they are independent hence their independence is characterized by $8-4=4$ relations.

Thus, the independences in the hypothesis are characterized by $1+1+1+1+4=8$ relations and the set of distributions fulfilling them has dimension $15-8=7$, while the set of independent random quadruples has dimension $4$. Since $7\gt4$, the former condition cannot imply the latter.

Comment: This addresses the original version of the post, which could (should) be restored.

Comment: Thx a lot Did, I think I got the idea of your conterexample. But I'm kinda confused atm, since I was quite sure that that was a standard result in the theory of random measures.

Comment: Am I supposed to answer this comment (since you posted it twice)? If you have a reference for this result you think holds, please share.

Comment: No sry, I just accidentially deleted my previous comment when trying to edit it.